# Put a symbol to the side of a row in a booktabs table

Tags: tables, booktabs

I would like to annotate one or more rows of a table with a star; the star should not be part of the table. I am using `booktabs`, so I cannot just add another column, or add the star to the rightmost entry, without the `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` extending also.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

The current table without annotation; I would like the table to look like this but with a $\star$ to the right of the final row:
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc|cc|c}\toprule
$P$ & $Q$ & $(P\rightarrow Q)$ & $\neg Q$ & $\neg P$  \\ \midrule
$T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $F$ \\
$T$ & $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $F$ \\
$F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $T$ \\
$F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

Including the annotation in the rightmost entry (undesirable):
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc|cc|l}\toprule
$P$ & $Q$ & $(P\rightarrow Q)$ & $\neg Q$ & $\neg P$  \\ \midrule
$T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $F$ \\
$T$ & $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $F$ \\
$F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $T$ \\
$F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T\quad\star$ \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

Adding an additional column (undesirable):
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc|cc|cc}\toprule
$P$ & $Q$ & $(P\rightarrow Q)$ & $\neg Q$ & $\neg P$  \\ \midrule
$T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $F$ \\
$T$ & $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $F$ \\
$F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $T$ \\
$F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $\star$\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

(I know that the vertical rules will get me into trouble with Mr Fear – in my defence truth tables are to my mind an intermediate case between a traditional table and a tableaux structure. I'm not concerned with fixing the broken vertical rules here.)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

[image]

Incidentally, you really need the vertical rules?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathrlap command
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc|cc|c@{}}
\toprule
$P$ & $Q$ & $(P\rightarrow Q)$ & $\neg Q$ & $\neg P$  \\ 
\midrule
$T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $F$ \\
$T$ & $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $F$ \\
$F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $T$ \\
$F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T\mathrlap{\quad\star}$ \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{\qquad}cc@{\qquad}c@{}}
\toprule
$P$ & $Q$ & $(P\rightarrow Q)$ & $\neg Q$ & $\neg P$  \\ 
\midrule
$T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $F$ \\
$T$ & $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $F$ \\
$F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $T$ \\
$F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T\mathrlap{\quad\star}$ \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. This environment (similar to `{tabular}`) allows you to add an exterior column with the key `last-col`. The environment takes into account the content of that column to compute the total width of the box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc@{\qquad}cc@{\qquad}c}[last-col]
\toprule
$P$ & $Q$ & $(P\rightarrow Q)$ & $\neg Q$ & $\neg P$  \\ 
\midrule
$T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $F$ \\
$T$ & $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $F$ \\
$F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $T$ \\
$F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $\star$ \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]